# Tunnel ODBC queries to REST endpoint

Tags: c#, database, rest, odbc, sqlanywhere

Is there an easy way to tunnel SQL-Queries which are send to an ODBC-Driver to a restful api, without writing my own ODBC driver using C/C++?

I need to do this, because i want redirect some odbc queries to a restful api. For example:

```
|----------|             |--------|                         |---------|
| Database |  <- read -  |  ODBC  | - send data to write -> | Restful |
|          |  - Write -> | Driver | <-     read data      - |   API   |
|----------|             |--------|                         |---------|
```

The database server (sql-anywhere) will embed the ODBC source as a remote server, so that i can read and write from it.

Thank you very much

Comment: Is there any update? Did you end up using SambaEngine SDK?

Comment: @SaschaVetter we end up writing our own driver using c#.

Comment: @BendEg How did you write a driver using C#, any resources you're able to share?

Comment: @superbadcodemonkey we wrote it in c, the sdk below was to expensive

Answer (score 3):

One way you can do this is by using the SimbaEngine SDK (http://www.simba.com/drivers/simba-engine-sdk/), which takes care of most of the ODBC work while letting you implement the communication pieces. You're still writing a driver (in C++, Java or C#), but the code required is much simpler and there's much less of it.

Comment: Yep, read and tried the sdk, but it seems to be a littble bit to expensive for my needs. If you need more features than i do, it is brilliant and really, really good...

Comment: @BendEg, reach out to Simba again and identify yourself in reference to this post, perhaps there's something that can be done.